# Remove groups in R if any row matches a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

Perhaps I've been phrasing my searches badly, but I haven't been able to find this exact circumstance.  I'm sure it's quite simple, I'm just not that well-versed.  I'm trying to remove ALL the elements associated with a group if ANY row in that group matches a condition.  For example, consider the following code

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

years <- c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003")
IDs <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
group <- c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")

people <- data.frame(years, IDs, group)

people <- people %>% group_by(IDs) %>% mutate(transition = ifelse(group != lag(group), "YES", "NO"))
```

I want to completely remove all records for IDs associated with people who have switched groups.  So if I group by `IDs` and ANY row has a `YES` in the `transition` column I want to filter that ID out completely.

Comment: Ironically, the `any()` function is a good general way to do this: `people |> group_by(IDs) |> filter(! any(transition == "YES"))`

Comment: However, you can go more directly, `people |> filter(n_distinct(group) == 1, .by = IDs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can try

```
> people %>%
+     filter(!any(na.omit(transition) == "YES"))
# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   IDs [1]
  years   IDs group transition
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 2000      2 B     NA
2 2001      2 B     NO
3 2002      2 B     NO        
4 2003      2 B     NO
```

or a shorter version with `%in%` (thanks for comments from @r2evans)

```
> people %>%
+     filter(!"YES" %in% transition)
# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   IDs [1]
  years   IDs group transition
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 2000      2 B     NA
2 2001      2 B     NO
3 2002      2 B     NO
4 2003      2 B     NO
```

Comment: Can simplify a little with `!"YES" %in% transition`, the `%in%` deals well with `NA` values (in case that's what you're thinking).

Comment: @r2evans yes, nice simplification, thanks!

Comment: Since `"YES"` is 1-long, the `!"YES" %in% ..` should always be length-1, so we don't need `any`, simply `filter(!"YES" %in% transition)`. Not that it's wrong, just not helping anything here. (The reason it works is through R's recycling of the length-1 `logical` vector to as many rows as exist in the current group.)

Comment: Another option is using `match`: `people %>% 
  group_by(IDs) %>% 
  mutate(transition = ifelse(group != lag(group), "YES", "NO")) %>%
  filter(is.na(match("YES", transition)))`

Comment: There would have to be a `group_by` in there right?  Like `people %>% group_by(IDs) %>% filter(!"YES" %in% transition)`

Comment: @jerH yes, `filter` should follow `group_by`